# can't access object property using interpolation in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm new to angular. developing a movie search app. almost completed the project but few things are not working. my app send api request to themoviedb.org and get JSON object as response. then read that JSON object and display the movies list. everything works fine. but I can't access the property of the Object. tried many things still can't solve it.

movie-detail.component.ts code:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DatabaseService } from 'src/app/service/database.service';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import {ImdbSingle } from '../../interface/imdb-single'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-movie-detail',
  templateUrl: './movie-detail.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./movie-detail.component.css']
})
export class MovieDetailComponent implements OnInit {

  imdbSI_data! : ImdbSingle[];
  movie_single_data! : ImdbSingle[];
  imdbObj_obj! : Object;

  constructor(private db:DatabaseService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getMovie();
  }

  getMovie(): void{

    const movieId = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    console.log(movieId);
    this.db.getMovie(movieId).subscribe(data => {
      this.imdbSI_data = data;
      this.imdbObj_obj = data;
      console.log("single movie detail",this.imdbSI_data);
      

    });
  }

}
```

movie-detail.component.html code

```
<p>movie-detail works!</p>

<div *ngFor="let movie of imdbSI_data | keyvalue">
    <h1 *ngIf="movie.key === 'title'">{{movie.value}}</h1>
    <img *ngIf="movie.key === 'poster_path' "src="https://www.themoviedb.org/t/p/w600_and_h900_bestv2{{movie.value}}">

</div>

<p>another loop</p>

<div>
    <p>{{imdbSI_data}}</p>
</div>
```

DatabaseService ts file code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Movie } from '../interface/movie';
import {Imdb} from '../interface/imdb'
import {ImdbSingle } from '../interface/imdb-single'
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class DatabaseService {

  private moviesUrl = 'api/movies';
  private showtimesUrl = 'api/showtimes';
  private imdbUrl = 'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=myapikey&query=';
  private imdbMovieDetail = '';


  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getMovies(movie_search : string | null): Observable<Imdb[]>{

    return this.http.get<Imdb[]>(this.imdbUrl+movie_search);
  
  }

  getMovie(movie_id: string | null){
    console.log("received id :",movie_id);
    this.imdbMovieDetail = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/"+movie_id+"?api_key=myapikey";
    return this.http.get<ImdbSingle[]>(this.imdbMovieDetail);
    
  }



}
```

the getMovies() function with imdb interface works fine. received the JSON object and [displayed it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fe7WY.jpg).

the problem is with the getMovie() function which will receive JSON object of the single selected movie. the JSON object received successfully. the problem is I can't access the Object property in component html template. Object image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nk0GK.jpg).

when trying to access the Object property in html template using interpolation like {{imdbSI_data.title}}. angular shows error : Property 'title' does not exist on type 'Object'. [image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ziueg.jpg).

I don't know how to access the property from Object directly.

Someone please help me. Thanks.

Comment: your `imdbSI_data! : ImdbSingle[];` variable is an array, so that variable does not have `title` property

Comment: @firatozcevahir thanks. how can I add property to imdbSI_data variable? any suggestion.

Comment: The response from the service is not an array. So you can declare your variable like this: `imdbSI_data! : ImdbSingle;` and to show `title` in your html, you can do something like this: `<p>{{imdbSI_data?.title}}</p>`